# Conversion of HTML( with inline css) to PDF using itext 2.1.7

Tags: java, itext

I want to convert one html page to pdf using itext 2.1.7. I have used HTMLWorker to convert the html file, but it not taking the inline css which I have used in the html. Below is my code snippet . Can anyone help to fix this issue..

```
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new 
FileOutputStream("D:/testpdf.pdf"));
document.open();
HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(htmlContent));
document.close();
```

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: That is because that old version of iText doesn't support it. Better upgrade to iText 7.1.1 + pdfHTML 2.0.1, see https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML for code examples.

Comment: iText 2.1.7 dates from 2009. The current year is 2018. Back in 2009, iText didn't support inline CSS. You should upgrade to a recent version of iText if you want support for inline CSS. Read the [chapter on CSS in the PDF to HTML tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-2-defining-styles-css). [Stop using iText 2.1.7 because it can no longer be used in a commercial context!](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5)

Comment: Thanks.. But IText 7 is paid version right,Thats why I am still prefer to use  2.1.7 . Is there any other method ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `itext7-7.0.2`  because `iText 2.1.7` didn't support inline CSS.

```
String htmlContent = "<html><body style='color:red'> PDF project </body></html>";

Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\testpdf.pdf")));
document.open();
HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(htmlContent));
document.close();
```